# How to pickle a class instance's variables selectively?

Tags: python, pickle

I have a class instance:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,shape):
        self.shape = shape
        self.matrix = numpy.zeros(shape)
```

I did some multiplication on `self.matrix`. When I am pickling the instance of class `A`, I don't want to pickle `self.matrix` for some reason.

Currently, my solution is to set `self.matrix = None` before pickle and reset `self.matrix` to `zeros(shape)` after loading from pickled file.

Is there a more elegant solution? Like the `transient` keyword in Java.

Comment: As a side note, if this is Python 2.x, you should be using `class A(object):`. Otherwise, you get old-style classes—and pickling is one of the places where old-style classes are different in ways you really don't want to learn if you don't have to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [hook methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances) to limit what is pickled and what is unpickled.

Here, you could use a `__getstate__` with corresponding `__setstate__` method:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.shape = shape
        self.matrix = numpy.zeros(shape)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self.shape,)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.shape, = state
        self.matrix = numpy.zeros(self.shape)
```

The `__setstate__` could be simplified to:

```
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__init__(*state)
```

if your `__init__` is reusable in this manner. In that case you can also use `__getinitargs__` instead of `__getstate__` and drop the `__setstate__` altogether:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.shape = shape
        self.matrix = numpy.zeros(shape)

    def __getinitargs__(self):
        return (self.shape,)
```

Comment: In this case, I think `__getinitargs__` would be simpler. Especially since you're defining `__setstate__` in a way that just calls `__init__` anyway…

Comment: @abarnert: I'm old-skool like that (e.g. I started with Python and pickling before Python 1.5)..

Comment: IIRC, the 1.6/2.0 docs (the first time I pickled anything) said that `__reduce__` was the only way to make extension types and Python classes act the same, so I didn't even look at the simpler alternatives until much later, by which point we had new-style classes and `__getinitargs__` and so on… Anyway, nowadays, I love protocols 3 and 4 and all the other nice new things that came with 3.x, and I hate pickling in 2.x…